# SWFObject 1.5 .write("identifier") not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, swfobject

I'm using swfobject 1.5 to place a shoutcast player on my page using `.write("indexplayer")` but it doesn't work in Internet Explorer 8. I've looked around and the only information I found on it was to try adding `defer="defer"` to the script tag, but this didn't work.

This is my current code:

```
<div id="indexplayer">
    <div id="player_error">FLASH / JAVASCRIPT ERROR</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var so = new SWFObject("/flash/scplayer.swf", "flashplayer", "280", "26", "8", "#171717");
    so.addParam("flashvars", "basic_variables_to_connect_to_shoutcast_server");
    so.addParam("wmode", "window");
    so.addParam("scale", "noscale");
    so.write("indexplayer");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use version 2.2 and do the following, works fine in every browser:

```
var flashvars = {
        file: 'PATH TO FILE IF THERE IS A FILE',
        autostart: true
    };
    var params = {
        allowfullscreen: true,
        allowscriptaccess: 'always',
        wmode: 'transparent'
    };
    var attributes = {};
    swfobject.embedSWF("/flash/scplayer.swf", 'ID OF THE ELEMENT TO RENDER FLASH IN', WIDTH_OF_THE_FLASH, HEIGHT_OF_THE_FLASH, "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
```